# Use `bazel query` inside a build file

Tags: bazel, bazel-query

I am using Bazel with Golang, but the question is no Go-specific. I have a common go directory structure:

```
cmd/
├── mycommand/
│   ├── BUILD.bazel
│   ├── main.go
│   └── somefolder
│       └── other.go
├── othercommand/
│   ├── BUILD.bazel
│   └── main.go
pkg/
└── mypackage/
    ├── BUILD.bazel
    └── init.go
BUILD.bazel
WORKSPACE
```

... and I'd like to reference targets under the `cmd` folder. I have a bazel query that will give me the list of those targets:

```
bazel query 'kind("go_binary", deps(//cmd/...))'
```

- `//cmd/mycommand:mycommand`
- `//cmd/othercommand:othercommand`

The question: How can I include this query in a BUILD.bazel file, something like the following:

```
pkg_tar(
    name = "release",
    srcs = kind("go_binary", deps(//cmd/...)),
    mode = "0644",
)
```

...which gives

```
ERROR: /some/path/BUILD.bazel:10:12: name 'kind' is not defined
ERROR: /some/path/BUILD.bazel:10:30: name 'deps' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build targets need to be statically referenced in BUILD files, so embedding queries as inputs to rule attributes does not work.

However, there are a couple of ways to dynamically generate targets to be used statically in the BUILD files:

1) Run a tool that generates a BUILD file before running Bazel. rules_go's Gazelle is a good example.

2) Write a [repository rule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/repository_rules.html) that invokes non-hermetic tools to dynamically generate targets that your BUILD files can depend on.

Note that you may come across the [`genquery`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#genquery) rule, which does let you perform a query on targets, but the rule outputs to a *file* during Bazel's execution phase, and not a Starlark list that can ingested into other rules' attributes during the analysis phase, which happens *before* the execution phase.

Comment: It seems like `bazel query ... | awk` is the generally accepted solution :facepalm:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/8609